# How to expand the OS backwards by backing up all the configs and programs and all?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, backup, timeshift

I wanted to keep all the configurations and programs and everything the same but wanted to uninstall windows. I thought of backing up using timeshift and then reinstalling the OS and then restoring from the snap taken, but it can't happen as it might leave my machine unbootable as timeshift can even alter the bootloader. So, please help me in how can I move my OS backwards while keeping all the things same. I want to get the space of /dev/sdb4 only not the earlier ones as it contains windows. An image of all the partitions:
[Please click here to see the image or paste the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8HEw.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8HEw.png)

Comment: What do you mean with "moving your OS backwards"?

Comment: I mean taking in the windows partition and mix it with Linux one. As it is behind the Linux one, so I wrote shift backwards.

Comment: OK, it is a repartitioning questions.

Comment: Yes, it is. I wanted to repartition my system.

Answer (score 0):

In gparted, you can move existing partitions without data loss. However, the process can take a long time.

- Delete sdb4. Click "Apply".
- Move sdb5 into the space freed by sdb4. Click "Apply". That will be a slow process.
- You could now resize sdb5 to fill the free space at the back

An alternative approach could be to leave your sdb5 where it is, i.e., leave your system files there. Then you could reformat sdb4 into a file format that supports linux file permissions, most obviously ext4, and use that as a partition for data storage (e.g. Pictures, Movies, etc.).

Another option is to turn sdb4 into a separate home, but as your root partition, at 36 GB, is rather large for the system only, you can easily leave your user configuration data there.

To make this a seamless experience for the end users, you can replace the relevant storage folders of the users by symlinks to the actual folders on sdb4. From the perspective of the user, this works exactly the same way as a physical folder.

Comment: Won't I have to tweek grub? Or will it adjust itself?